# Databases using JSON as storage/transport format

Tags: json, mongodb, couchdb, dbslayer, database

How many database systems there are that use JSON for storage or transport? I know of:

- [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/)
- [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home)
- [DBSlayer](http://code.nytimes.com/projects/dbslayer)

I remember I saw yet another vendor in a SO user's profile. That systems was using what they called binary JSON, but I can't remember the name of the product.

Lately, it appears that more and more DB projects are looking towards JSON for persistence storage. Some of them are even embracing HTTP as a transport layer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MongoDb is the one that uses a binary JSON storage format.  I don't know if there is another that is document oriented.  Most of the others are key value stores and can only retrieve an object based on one key.

Comment: One minor thing to note is that "binary JSON" is sort of misnomer: it should be more like "binary JSON-like format". This because it has both more datatypes than JSON (extension); and because it can not express all legal JSON values and constructs (subset) due to size limitations (size prefixes of limited size).

Answer (score 14):

Persevere is another DB that is loaded up with JSON:

http://www.persvr.org/

Primary transport is JSON HTTP/REST

Data is stored as JSON

It has a native JS/JSON client for running directly from the browser.

If you want a schema then it is defined using JSON

Comment: Sounds interesting, any experiences with performance?

Answer (score 9):

This is a non-authoritative list.

- [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/)
- [FleetDB](http://fleetdb.org/)
- [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)
- [OrientDB](http://www.orientdb.org/)
- [Apache Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/)
- [Redis](http://redis.io/)
- [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/)

Source: [Wikipedia - Document Oriented Databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database)

Answer (score 4):

postgresql recently added a json datatype

[postgre json datatype](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.2#JSON_datatype)

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB does not use JSON but BSON.

[RethinkDB](http://www.rethinkdb.com) is a document oriented database with a JSON data model, which supports sharding and replication

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Basho's Riak.  It has a number of things in common with CouchDB: Erlang-based, Javascript MapReduce API, HTTP transport, JSON document format and multi-master replication.  It doesn't aim to be quite as simple as CouchDB (CouchDB is more "opinionated"), but they give you a lot of options for adjusting CAP parameters to meet the needs of your application, per-write.

Comment: Also has automatic scale-out and scale-in. Another big plus over CouchDB, for some use cases, is Riak's support for "links" (essentially pointers). It's a real shame it hasn't caught on as much as some of the others...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store your JSON document in AppEngine's Datastore, you can have a look at Ubud-db, https://bitbucket.org/f94os/ubud-db/wiki
Ubud-db is a Document store on AppEngine with a REST-JSON API.