# regex syntax to get data into separated variables

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have this code inserted into the database: `{"2":{"qty":1,"price":"10.00","room_id":{"1002":"1"}},"1":{"qty":2,"price":"35.00","room_id":["2"]},"3":{"qty":1,"price":"18.00","room_id":["1"]}}`

I want to get the values FROM `{"2":{"qty":1,"price":"10.00","room_id":{"1002":"1"}} TO "3":{"qty":1,"price":"18.00","room_id":["1"]}}` and store each digit in a separate variable.

What would be the regular expression to match this?

Answer (score 11):

> what's the sytax i should use as regex please?

The answer is "none". You should not try to parse JSON using regexes. Use the [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function instead.

Comment: sorry, posted my answer as comment to your, it's fixed now

Comment: @PeterButkovic No problem, I removed my comment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1344461

Comment: @C0deH4cker Been there, seen that :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store `json` data in the database, why don't you use some `noSQL` one that does `json` internally?

I'd go for `MongoDB`. Or possibly any of these: [Databases using JSON as storage/transport format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853265/databases-using-json-as-storage-transport-format)